# port apache rewrite to nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

I  have nginx acting as a reverse proxy to apache.

I have an assets directory with static files that is being served by nginx

```
location /assets {
  alias   /var/public/assets;
  expires     1h;
}
```

However, some of the jpegs served from that directory have a particular format
ie

```
/assets/test.jpg?p=2&project=wert
```

I want these urls to be rewritten by nginx so that they are processed by the backend service

I have the below apache rewrite that does what I want

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=[0-9]{1,2}&project=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)\.(jpe?g)$ /process/assets/$1.$2 [L]
```

What is the equivalent for nginx and should I put it in the above location directive or somewhere else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($query_string ~ "q=[0-9]{1,2}&project=(\w+)$"){
    rewrite ^/assets/(.*)\.(jpe?g)$ /process/assets/$1.$2 break;
}
```

Comment: Will try thanks. Shall this reside inside the location directive I mention?

Comment: If it's not, change "break" to "last". There exists more elegant solution with just rewrite, if this doesn't work - I'll write it.

Comment: Hi. I tried it and nginx complains:  "alias" could not be used in location "/assets" where URI was rewritten

Comment: I moved it outside the location block and it seems to be working. Will test some more